# Performance difference between select and select with order by

Tags: sql, database, indexing, db2

I have a table T1 with seven columns with name c1,c2,c3,.... c7.
All columns are of type varchar ranging from 10 - 500, but mostly are of size 500.
Table has approximately 24k rows. When I execute

```
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

it takes more than 1 min to fetch all rows.But when I run same query with additional order by clause

```
SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY C1;
```

it takes less then 25 secs to load completed data.

**Note**: There are no indices on table.

Tool I am using to query is Embarcadero DBArtisan and Database is IBM DB2 9.7+.
Also server and client are several thousand kilometres apart.

I am bit confused why it is taking less time with order by clause and time difference is huge.

Comment: Did you try running the queries in a reverse order: the one with `order by` first?

Comment: Yes, I tired that to still the result was almost same.

Comment: I don't know about DBArtisan, but client tools usually provide info about the actual runtime on the DBMS and the time to transfer the data across the network. Those time differences might be mainly related to the network.

Comment: But even let say it is total time( execution + transfer), it was consistent for past week.

Comment: I cannot see how this may be possible if all that you say is true. In the absence of indexes any query against a regular table will result in a table scan. By adding `ORDER BY` you incur, in addition to that table scan, a sort and another table scan against the sorted temporary table, so the latter query cannot possibly be faster than the former. Either you are measuring something else, or T1 is not a regular table but a view and by adding ordering you change the query execution plan. I'm sure DBArtisan can generate plans for both queries and thus explain the mystery.

Comment: T1 is an ordinary table at least the way I created it. Not sure if DB2 is configure to do something special while creating table. Also, even if indices are there on c1, c2, c3 still performance and difference is same let me check the query plant get back to you. I will post more details tomorrow.

Comment: Today, I tried it again but now time seems to be almost same for both queries, tried all possible combination. Not sure where issue was, but now it make sense.